# Should I Use An Always-Running Console Program on Server to Do Task

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, server

What I want to achieve is quite simple, and it can be accomplished by a always-running console program like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true) {

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            if(now==timeToRunTask)
                 runMyTask();//e.g. send an email to Joe

        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if this approach is very inefficient in terms of what I'm trying to achieve. And I saw some information about using Task Scheduler so I wonder if I should use that. I'm using Windows Server. But I'd like to know why I shouldn't use the above approach first. Thanks!

Comment: if now != timetoRunTask you can sleep the thread for difference between now and timetoRunTask, instead of keep it running.

Comment: @Panther Make sense, thanks! If I sleep the thread, then running my console program isn't wasting too much power and is a fine approach now?

Comment: Yuo can use [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to do this work

Comment: Use a windows service with a timer instead. It will be much cleaner and maintainable.

Comment: This is basically a busy-wait approach which is inefficient in terms of CPU utilization. If it is possible to 'predict' timeToRunTask, you would better go for things such as Task Scheduler. Another thing is that using a console program's main thread for busy-wait will cause it to stuck always.

Comment: I am not familiar with C# much but you must some scheduling framework based on quartz better to use them as they are tested code. Insteading of putting our efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you stick with this approach, you still need a way to launch the console app.  You can't just log in and run it, because it will terminate when you log off.

The simplest approach is to use the tools Windows provides, in this case Task Scheduler.  You can configure a task to launch your application on an interval.  Then in the application, just run the task once and exit.

If you truly require that the application stays running indefinitely, I recommend moving from a console app to a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

On a server you have little to no control over the app. E.g. if the server reboots (due to installed updates for example), you have to restart the app manually.

If you only have this one app, I'd recommend making it a windows service. It's incredibly simple to do in C#. If you need multiple tasks in the long run, having multiple services (maybe even on multiple servers) for it can become quite the hassle, though.